Install usbmuxd v1.1.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I've searched around and it seems that usbmuxd v1.1.2 is needed for idevicerestore to fully work.
Apparently, the older v1.1.1 is unable to get the device to go into restore mode meaning the ipad stops at the point where it asks me to connect to itunes.
If you can point me in the right place to get the whole process to work(installing usbmuxd v1.1.2 and getting idevicerestore to update my ipad OS to the latest) I would be very grateful.
Thanks.
